# MODx issue, cannot be crawled

Tags: seo, googlebot, modx

I have a page https://zabery365.ru/removal/bath for my client. Please look at the code. I have a big trouble - for a 3 weeks it has not been crawled, pagespeed also said that there are no data. GSC said that the page does not exist.

This problem starts from the push of a new html with schema.org patterns. The server where it was placed - MODx. I was asked on Google Forum 3 times, but no one answered me.

All files have accesss in robots.txt

by the way in process of writing i was pushed the page with simple hello for a minute, it was not indexed too. Therefore I presume to think that it is problem on server side of MODx.

The web site does not appears and does not shows the content with 404 error. What mistake in the server of MODx that it does not shows the content for crawlers?

Comment: Google trusts a few sites enough to index new content from them right away.  However for most sites it can take weeks. For new or untrusted sites it can take months.

Comment: This is website that has been working for a 4 years, I just have been changed a page